# How to add brackets to list

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

I have for example set of points

> p={1/5,1/2}

and I would like to add brackets to the list, so I would like to get a set of points

> p2={{1/5},{1/2}}

I know how to remove brackets, but I cant find if is possible also to add brackets. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Try `p2=Transpose[{p}]`

Comment: `List/@p` (or `Map[List,p]`) also works

Comment: The fastest method should be `Partition[p,1]`.

Comment: Brackets {} stand for `List`, I suggest to go through some sort of introduction tutorial. It will make you life easier.